# How to make a page scroll to bottom of image

Tags: html, css

I dont really have anything to show, but i'll try to explain.

I am using HTML and CSS and i have a background image the size of the moon. (3840x18509 pixels). How can i add this as a background on the page, get it to scale automatically to the screen, and make it scrollable? What i mean by that is that i want to be able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the long picture. using :cover is not doing it, and when i set height:18509px; The image gets wider than it's supposed to be so that it cuts out on the sides.

I want the website to be as wide as the original picture, and as high as the original picture. I want to show the entire picture in a way that it fits the screen width, but must be scrolled downwards to reach the bottom. Thanks in advance.

```css
body, html {
    
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0; 
    background-image: url("HuronWP.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; I dont want it to cut the image height, 
    i want to scroll down to see the rest.
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: It's very helpful to everyone to provide your code !

Comment: Do you definitely know the aspect ratio of your moon image in advance? It sounds as though you do but thought I'd better check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact size of the image you simply have to set the `aspect-ratio` of `<body>` to match the image: `body { aspect-ratio: 3840 / 18509; }`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/3840x18509.jpg');
  aspect-ratio: 3840 / 18509;
}
```

Alternativly you could insert the image directly and use `width: 100%` to fit the screen while maintaining its aspect-ratio.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* for styling purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/3840x18509.jpg">
```

Comment: Just an observation that aspect-ratio is only just coming into Safari (with version 15).

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to scroll you image whenever it becomes wider or longer than your page. You can do this simply using `css` `overflow` `property`.

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Just adding this to our code it will work fine.
Whenever the image height or width will be larger than you container then it will automatically be a scrollable.

Here I have created a div class and put my image inside this div.

```
<div class="image">
  <img
    src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
    alt="img"
  />
</div>
```

Now I am changing the `height` and `width` of my `<img>` so that it will `overflow` the `<div>` class.

height and width of `image.`

```
img {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
  }
```

height and width of outer `div`

```
.image{
    height: 900px;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

This `property` will be `valid` only when the outer `div` must have smaller `height` and `width` than the `inner`,

Comment: you miss the question. He does not want to scroll the image horizontally. He wants the image to fit the viewports width and be able to scroll down to the bottom of the image while it overflows the viewport vertically. None of that will ensure it as the viewports are not all exactly 900px wide. A responsive solution would work with relative units as my example at the bottom.